# How to group by 1 field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query on oracle which gives me result like:

---

sportsman1 coach1 result_of_function

sportsman1 coach2 result_of_function

sportsman2 coach3 result_of_function

---

But I need to have smth like:

---

sportsman1

coach1 result_of_function

coach2 result_of_function

sportsman2

coach3 result_of_function

---

```sql
select  a.fullname as Sportsman, t.fullname as Coach, date_raz(a.dateinclub, b.dateovertrain) as MONTHS
from athlet a, trainer t,black_couch b
where t.id=a.couch and b.couch=t.id and b.athlete=a.id;
```

What shoud I add to the query?

Comment: There's nothing you can add to the query. A result set, like a table is composed of rows and columns. You, however, want 1 row with 1 column, then 2 row with 2 columns, then 1 row with 1 column, then 1 row with 2 columns. This is really more of an operation for your UI that displays this data then it is for your database.

Comment: If you're executing in SQLPlus, it's possible you could do something using commands like BREAK and COLUMN to format the presentation of the query results.